# Binding vs Assignment

Tags: ruby, binding, functional-programming, elixir, variable-assignment

I've read a number of articles on the difference between `assignment` and `binding`, but it hasn't clicked yet (specifically in the context of an imperative language vs one without mutation).

I asked in IRC, and someone mentioned these 2 examples illustrate the difference, but then I had to go and I didn't see the full explanation.

Can someone please explain how/why this works in a detailed way, to help illustrate the difference?

**Ruby**

```
x = 1; f = lambda { x }; x = 2; f.call
#=> 2
```

**Elixir**

```
x = 1; f = fn -> x end; x = 2; f.()
#=> 1
```

Comment: Your current understanding is plain wrong. `x = 1` is “make `x` local variable to point to the memory address that contains `1`,” and `x = 2` is respectively “make `x` local variable to point to the memory address that contains `2`.” You can compare `x.__id__` in both cases, they differ, while `x.__id__` and `1.__id__` are apparently the same. When you do `x1 = %w|a b c|; x2 = x1`, then _yes_, `x1` and `x2` share the same memory.

Comment: Numbers as I have said already, are immutable in ruby. As well as atoms, `nil` and booleans. `a = %w|a b c|; b = a; a.shift` will change `b` because it _mutates_ `a`, while `a = %w|a b c|; b = a; a = %w|d e f|` _won’t change `b`_, because `a` is _reassigned_.

Comment: In the ruby example, `f` does not point anywhere. When it gets called, and it meets the local variable `x`, it looks up the scope for `x` local variable, finds it (currently it’s equal to `2`) and uses it. Ruby is an _interpreted_ language.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense regarding those immutable data types. So in some sense, ruby behaves identically to elixir then only when dealing only with those immutable data types... right?

Comment: Ruby does not behave identically to Elixir by any means. Elixir is _compiled_ language. Ruby is not. Yes, GC takes some effort to not produce tons of numbers, but for the developer, it’s almost transparent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've heard this explanation before and it seems pretty good:

> You can think of binding as a label on a suitcase, and assignment as a
>   suitcase.

In other languages, where you have assignment, it is more like putting a value in a suitcase. You actually change value that is in the suitcase and put in a different value.

If you have a suitcase with a value in it, in **Elixir**, you put a label on it. You can change the label, but the value in the suitcase is still the same.

So, for example with:

```elixir
iex(1)> x = 1
iex(2)> f = fn -> x end
iex(3)> x = 2
iex(4)> f.()
1
```

1. You have a suitcase with `1` in it and you label it `x`.
2. Then you say, "Here, Mr. Function, I want you to tell me what is in *this suitcase* when I call you."
3. Then, you take the label off of the suitcase with `1` in it and put it on another suitcase with `2` in it.
4. Then you say "Hey, Mr. Function, what is in that suitcase?"

He will say "1", because the suitcase hasn't changed. Although, you have taken your label off of it and put it on a different suitcase.

Comment: MMMmmmmm... this is a great explanation. I need to think this over. This brings up so many more questions though. Is the first suitcase with the `1` in it "kept around" anywhere even though it has no references to it anymore? Or... is the `x` inside the function actually a reference, and at the end of those 4 lines there's actually 2 references now, even though they share the same name (one reference of `x` in lambda -> 1, and another reference from the `x` on line 3 to `2`

Comment: I think this one helped me understand it the most, even though it was the least technical (wasn't expecting that).

Comment: This example is actually talking about closures. The environment in which the function was created is one in which x equals 1.

Answer (score 6):

After a while, I came up with the answer that is probably the best explanation of the difference between “binding” and “assignment”; it has nothing in common with what I have written in another answer, hence it’s posted as a separate answer.

In any functional language, where everything is immutable, there is no meaningful difference between terms “binding” and “assignment.” One might call it either way; the common pattern is to use the word “binding,“ explicitly denoting that it’s a value *bound* to a variable. In Erlang, for instance, one can not *rebound* a variable. In Elixir this is possible (why, for God’s sake, José, what for?)

Consider the following example in Elixir:

```
iex> x = 1
iex> 1 = x
```

The above is *perfectly valid Elixir code*. It is evident, one cannot assign anything to *one*. It is neither assignment nor binding. It is *matching*. That is how `=` is treated in Elixir (and in Erlang): `a = b` fails if both are bound *to different* values; it returns RHO if they match; it binds LHO to RHO if LHO is not bound yet.

In Ruby it differs. There *is* a significant difference between assignment (copying the content,) and binding (making a reference.)

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Do you know any articles where I can learn how binding/assignment work in ruby (at a low level, how scopes also affect it, etc). I tried Googling but get meh results. I still am mulling all this over (specifically your ruby example). I get pattern matching but some of these other answers make me think I'm still missing something cause it doesn't 100% click.

Comment: Everything in Ruby is passed by reference, save for few exceptions: numbers, booleans, nil, and symbols. There is no explicit “assignment” syntax in ruby. When one needs it, one uses `Object#clone` and/or `Object#dup`. I am unaware of any written materials on the subject, I personally prefer to read source code when I lack understanding, and Ruby is luckily open source.

Comment: Fora anyone else reading this, I found some great info here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/01/comparing-elixir-and-erlang-variables/

Answer (score 2):

Elixir vs Ruby might not be the best contrast for this. In Elixir, we can readily "re-assign" the value of a previously assigned named variable. The two anonymous-function examples you provided demonstrate the difference in how the two languages assign local variables in them. In Ruby, the variable, meaning the memory reference, is assigned, which is why when we change it, the anonymous function returns the current value stored in that memory-reference. While in Elixir, the value of the variable at the time the anonymous function is defined (rather than the memory reference) is copied and stored as the local variable.

In Erlang, Elixir's "parent" language, however, variables as a rule are "bound." Once you've declared the value for the variable named `X`, you are not allowed to alter it for the remainder of the program and any needed alterations would need to be stored in new named variables. (There is a way to reassign a named variable in Erlang but it is not the custom.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to understand the difference, would be to compare the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) that is used by the language interpreter/compiler to produce machine-/byte-code.

Let’s start with ruby. Ruby does not provide the AST viewer out of the box, so I will use [`RubyParser`](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) gem for that:

```
> require 'ruby_parser'
> RubyParser.new.parse("x = 1; f = -> {x}; x = 2; f.()").inspect

#=> "s(:block, s(:lasgn, :x, s(:lit, 1)), 
#    s(:lasgn, :f, s(:iter, s(:call, nil, :lambda), 0, s(:lvar, :x))),
#    s(:lasgn, :x, s(:lit, 2)), s(:call, s(:lvar, :f), :call))"
```

The thing we are looking for is the latest node in the second line: there is *`x` variable inside the proc*. In other words, ruby expects the bound variable there, named `x`. At the time the proc is evaluated, `x` has a value of `2`. Hence the the proc returns `2`.

Let’s now check Elixir.

```
iex|1 ▶ quote do
...|1 ▶   x = 1
...|1 ▶   f = fn -> x end
...|1 ▶   x = 2
...|1 ▶   f.()
...|1 ▶ end

#⇒ {:__block__, [],
# [
#   {:=, [], [{:x, [], Elixir}, 1]},
#   {:=, [], [{:f, [], Elixir}, {:fn, [], [{:->, [], [[], {:x, [], Elixir}]}]}]},
#   {:=, [], [{:x, [], Elixir}, 2]},
#   {{:., [], [{:f, [], Elixir}]}, [], []}
# ]}
```

Last node in the second line is ours. It still contains `x`, but during a compilation stage this `x` will be evaluated to it’s currently assigned value. That said, `fn -> not_x end` will result in compilation error, while in ruby there could be literally anything inside a proc body, since it’ll be evaluated *when called*.

In other words, Ruby uses a current *caller’s* context to evaluate proc, while Elixir uses a closure. It grabs the context it encountered the function definition and uses it to resolve all the local variables.

Comment: Trying a Ruby interpreter, defining `f = lambda { x }` before `x` is defined seems to result in an error when calling `f.call` even if `x` is then defined (after the anonymous function is declared).

Comment: @גלעדברקן Good catch; this looks like a bug/undefined behaviour in ruby parser. Javascript has hoisting for this, ruby to some extent does have as well, but here it for some reason fails. I’ll fail an issue to their tracker.

Comment: Wow crazy catch... and @mudasobwa thank you for that explanation. I see JS is similar to ruby in how it uses the caller's context at run time. All that makes sense, but in the elixir example, what is happening behind the scenes when it compiles the `x` in the lambda? Is it still a pointer at all or is it literally replacing the `x` with a `1` by value? Does that mean in elixir there are no references at all (when "binding")?

Comment: Well, there are _no references_ in Elixir in the sense we tend to use in OOP. For the GC purposes, in fact, nearly everything _is a reference_, but the margins here are too small to describe this. In Elixir _everything_ is immutable. That means one might effectively discard `x` and replace it with `1` during compilation since there is no chance `x` might have changed. So yes, in the compiled code (BEAM) there will be `1` and no trail of `x` ever.

Comment: I'm sure some of this is redundant with what you have already explained, but would you mind checking out my edits? I appreciate the help, I'm just hammering out the last little bits that are confusing.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Variables are defined from the point on that the first assignment to them is parsed. Since there is no local variable `x` defined at that point, `x` is a message send, calling the method `x` on `self` with no arguments. The fact that `x` gets defined later is irrelevant, what matters is if it is defined at the point the block gets created.

Answer (score 1):

Binding refers to particular concept used in expression-based languages that may seem foreign if you're used to statement-based languages.  I'll use an ML-style example to demonstrate:

```
let x = 3 in
   let y = 5 in
       x + y

val it : int = 8
```

The `let... in` syntax used here demonstrates that the binding `let x = 3` is scoped only to the expression following the `in`.  Likewise, the binding `let y = 5` is only scoped to the expression `x + y`, such that, if we consider another example:

```
let x = 3 in
   let f () =
       x + 5
   let x = 4 in
       f()

val it : int = 8
```

The result is still 8, even though we have the binding `let x = 4` above the call to `f()`.  This is because `f` itself was bound in the scope of the binding `let x = 3`.

Assignment in statement-based languages is different, because the variables being assigned are not scoped to a particular expression, they are effectively 'global' for whatever block of code they're in, so reassigning the value of a variable changes the result of an evaluation that uses the same variable.